# Replacing column values with loop result pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop

I have dataframe that looks like this:

```
State   State_theft_sum Model_1 Model_year_1
Alabama 2154    Chevrolet Pickup (Full Size)    2005.0  
Alaska  547 Chevrolet Pickup (Full Size)    2003.0
Arizona 5270    Honda Accord    1997.0
```

DF goes on and on, so changing values separately isn't the way. I though i might be able to replace them using result of loop which would format string as I want it to be, here is the loop:

```
for model_year in df_total['Model_year_1']:
    model_year = model_year.split('.')
    model_year = model_year[0]
    print(model_year)
```

Result of the loop:

```
2005
2003
1997
2004
1996
1997
(...)
```

I need this to be formatted as a string as I will use it as text for Choropleth chart.

Is there any way I can change the values inside a column of DF without needing to create new DF from the loop and then joining them and after that deleting the column with .0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably just convert it to a `float`, then to an `int` and then to a `str` to avoid the loop.

```
df["Model_year_1"] = df["Model_year_1"].astype('float').astype('int').astype('str')
```

Comment: I tried doing that but then i have this error: "ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '2005.0'"

Comment: I didn't realize the years were strings. I've updated the answer.